# How to check if string has letter in second character with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Say I wanted to create an ID number such as `1A45` or `4F01`.

What would the regex be to make sure that the string had exactly one letter as the second character?

I am unsure how to check for specific combinations of characters.

What I have so far is:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(txtTrainID.Text, @"^[\w,\d,\w,\w]+$"))
```

Which is obviously completely wrong, I've had trouble trying to find a decent simple answer to this anywhere.

Comment: What about other three characters? I guess you have [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the only requirement (and I am sure it's not), use anchors and a character class in the second position as in

```
^.[A-Za-z]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/N04LS4/1/).

---

What you *probably* mean, comes down to:

```
^\d[a-zA-Z]\d{2}$
```

The latter means *one digit*, *one of a-zA-Z*, followed by *two other digits* and the end of the string. See [**another demo**](https://regex101.com/r/N04LS4/2/) on the same site.